# Is my thinking for the total number of operations in the code-snippet below valid? (Big-O notation)

Tags: java, numbers, big-o, operations

```
public class foo{   
    public static void main(String[] args){
         int a = 1;
         int b = 1;
         int n = 4;

         //Focus is on the below for-loop
         for(int x=1;x<=n;x++){           
             c=a+b;
         }
    }
}
```

- x=1  --> O(1) //One assignment statement
- x<=n --> O(n+1) //checks n times and then a following time
- x++  --> O(n) //increments n times
- c=a+b --> O(4n) //increments n times, but the statement itself has four operations, LOAD A + LOAD B + ADD + STORE C

Now how would I combine these? i.e. Do I add, or multiply, and why?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: That won't compile, to start with. Always start with valid code...

Comment: The question doesn't really pertain to operational code... I'll change it however, thanks.

Comment: The code still does not compile with your edit.

Comment: @MuratK. OP just clarified that this is just a snippet for time-complexity analysis, rather than execution.

Comment: Sorry I cannot change it to compilable code right this minute but I will definitely come back later.

Comment: @MuratK. I modified the code to compile, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thinking is valid, but that is not `BigOh`
To calculate `BigOh` you need [Asymptotic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis)

There is an awesome answer by a university professor [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it), you should check out the last part of his answer.

Time complexity of your code would be `O(n)`

Comment: Thank you very much! Will check out these resources. Why would the complexity be O(n) and not say, O(3n+2).

Comment: Constants are omitted during asymptotic analysis.

Comment: @AriK If you are satisfied with my answer to your question, please mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is my thinking for the total number of operations in the code-snippet below valid? (Big-O notation)

No because Big-O is not about code operations at the level that you are counting them.  To quote this [descent page about Big-O](https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/):

> Big O notation is used in Computer Science to describe the performance or complexity of an algorithm. Big O specifically describes the worst-case scenario, and can be used to describe the execution time required or the space used (e.g. in memory or on disk) by an algorithm.

In your case you have:

> O(N) describes an algorithm whose performance will grow linearly and in direct proportion to the size of the input data set.

As `N` increases, your for loop increases linearly so your code is O(N).